# Filter post by clickable year

Tags: archives

How can I get all the year of posts in archive.php and put it on the list?

```
2016 | 2017 | 2018
```

And after clicking any year, It will show the posts of the selected year `www.example.com/post_type/2018.`

Do I need to rewrite rules to make this done?

Comment: For built in posts or for your custom post type?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, for my custom post type

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, I am asking about the year only not the month

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by Using Simple Yearly Archive Plugin. It allows you to use different shortcode based on your requirements.

For custom post type you can use like: [SimpleYearlyArchive type="yearly_past"]

Plugin link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/